# table from .txt file into vectors in c++

Tags: c++, vector, multiple-columns

I have a text file with the following format:

```
string1   int1   int6
string2   int2   int7
string3   int3   int8
string4   int4   int9
string5   int5   int10
```

The first column contains strings, the second and third contain integers.

I want to put each column in a separate vector, how can I do that?

Comment: Please show us some code that you have implemented so far. You might show us how you are reading the file so that a suggestion can be made about moving that data to a vector. You should also show an actual sample of the file you are reading from. At least a few lines if it has more than one line.

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> v1;
std::vector<int> v2, v3;

for (std::string line; std::getline(infile, line); )
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    std::string s;
    int a, b;

    if (!(iss >> s >> a >> b >> std::ws) || iss.get() != EOF)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error parsing line '" << line << "', skipping\n";
        continue;
    }

    v1.push_back(std::move(s);
    v2.push_back(a);
    v3.push_back(b);
}
```

Comment: It seems like most basic C++ questions I see on here boil down to "You should look up `stringstream`". :) +1

Answer (score 0):

First you need to read the file in line by line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::ifstream file;
std::string line;
std::vector<std::string> lines;
file.open("myfile.txt");

while (std::getline(file, line))
    lines.push_back(line);
```

Then you need to separate the words/integers (I assume they're separated by 
spaces):

```
size_t pos = 0;
int oldpos = 0;
std::vector<std::string> words;

for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i)
{
    pos = lines.at(i).find_first_of(' ', oldpos);

    while (pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        words.push_back(lines.at(i).substr(oldpos, pos - oldpos));
        oldpos = pos + 1;
        pos = lines.at(i).find_first_of(' ', oldpos);
    }

    words.push_back(lines.at(i).substr(oldpos, pos - oldpos));

    oldpos = 0;
}
```

Then you need to transfer contents of this large vector to 3 smaller vectors:

```
std::vector<std::string> strings;
std::vector<int> ints1;
std::vector<int> ints2;

for (int j = 0; j < words.size(); j += 3)
{
    strings.push_back(words.at(j));
    ints1.push_back(std::atoi(words.at(j + 1).c_str()));
    ints2.push_back(std::atoi(words.at(j + 2).c_str()));
}
```

The reason I think this code is better than the answer above is because firstly, it allows you to select the delimiter e.g. if you use commas instead of spaces. Also it's expandable - just add a few more vectors and change j += 3 to however many vectors you have.